# PGFPlots: Use hexadecimal floats

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using the `otfprofile` command to generate from some data a LaTeX-file containing PGFPlots. Unfortunately, the program outputs a hexadecimal floating notation (e.g. `0x1.ap+6`), that both lualatex (version 0.95.0) and pdflatex (version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17) do not understand.

How could I solve this problem?

Edit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\nonstopmode
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[linkcolor=red,pagecolor=red,pdfborder={1 1 1}]{hyperref}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\textwidth=16.1cm \textheight=27.0cm \topmargin=-1.8cm
\oddsidemargin=0.1cm \evensidemargin=0.1cm \footskip=45pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=0x1p+4cm, height=0x1p+3cm,
  axis x line=bottom,x axis line style={-,line width=1pt},
  axis y line=left,y axis line style={-,line width=1pt},
  enlarge y limits={value=0.02,upper},
  ymin=0,ymajorgrids,xminorgrids,minor x tick num=1,
title=P2P Number of Messages (average)
,ylabel={},
x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east,font=\ttfamily \footnotesize},
tick align=outside,
tick style={line cap=round,line width=0.5pt,color=black,
      major tick length=4pt,minor tick length=8pt},
major x tick style={line width=1, color=white},
scaled y ticks=true,
bar width=8pt,
minor grid style={color=gray, line width=0.5pt, dashed},
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=15.5,
xtick={0,...,15},
xticklabels={
},]
\addplot[ybar, draw=black, mark=none, fill=red, xshift=-4]
  coordinates{
(0,0x1.38p+8)};
\addplot[ybar, draw=black, mark=none, fill=blue, xshift=4]
  coordinates{
(0,0x1.ap+6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is one of several graphs.
The error message:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.3' (in '0x1.38p+8'). (0,0x1.38p+8)};
```

This notation is analogue to `1.3e+3` or `1.3 * 10^3`, just with hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: can you add some more numbers and possibly with a MWE about what to do with them?

Comment: If I recall correctly, TeX does not support non-integer hexadecimals.

Comment: `xintexpr+xintbinhex` supports fractional hexadecimals, but it requires uppercase letters and has no built-in support for "p". I tried nevertheless replacing "p+8" for example by "*16^8", and it could work (but the manual intervention could as well be occasion to copy-paste from a scientific calculator directly) but there are dimension too large errors from pgfplots. For example `width=0x1p+4cm` means `16^4cm`, right? That is `65536cm` which is way beyond TeX max dimension which is less than `576cm`.

Comment: I can confirm that in principle you could do things like `coordinates{(0,\xinttheiexpr[5] "1.38*16^1\relax)};` but as you see the "p" was handled manually and only the `"1.38` fractional hexadecimal remained. Also, i had to use braces like `width={\xinttheiexpr[5]16^2\relax cm},`. Needs packages xintexpr and xintbinhex. Only very partial solution... even if parsing of "p" was done one would need to add manually the `\xinttheiexpr[5]..\relax` wrappers. And do manually the uppercasing... :-(

Comment: edit: on further investigation it appears the notation `p` is for a power of 2, not 16, which is rather counter-intuitive for mathematics but surely has its reasons in computer science!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input.

I solved the problem with a small Python-program, that converts all occurences of hexadecimal numbers into decimal representation. The result compiled without any further errors.

If anyone has a similar problem, here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, re

resultFile = open(sys.argv[1].split('.')[0] + "_processed.tex", "w")
for row in open(sys.argv[1]):
    resultFile.write( re.sub('0x[0-9a-fA-F]+\.?[0-9a-fA-F]*p[+-][0-9]+', lambda m: str(float.fromhex(m.group())), row) )
```

Usage: `python <scriptname> <file>`, the output is stored in `<file>_processed.tex`

Comment: yes, good way! no problem with too large dimensions though? (`0x1p+4cm`)

Comment: Dunno why, but surprisingly e.g. `0x1p+4 = 16.0`, thus no problem with the dimensions. Seems to be so, because `0x1p+4` is a floating point value, not an integer.

Comment: `0x1p+4 = 16.0` ? then `p` means `2 to the power`, not `16 to the power...` ?

Comment: ah, according to http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/ indeed `p` stand for power of 2. Then this is *not*  hexadecimal floating point for mathematicians!

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for digging that out.

Comment: it is part of the [C99 standard page 57](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) but I had never encountered that... (shame on me).